# C++ getline and append

Tags: c++, string, append

I'm trying to write a very simple program that reads its standard input line by line (until "end" appears at the beginning of a line). At the same time, it tries to construct a new string that contains the concatenation of all the lines.

The behavior is quite puzzling. The lines are correctly read (as shown by the `cout << current << endl` line). However, the constructed string isn't what I expect. Instead, it contains only the last read. However, if I replace `construct.append(current)` by `construct.append("foo")`, it works perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>                                                               
#include <string>                                                                 
#include <cassert>                                                               

using namespace std;                                                              

int main() {                                                                      
    string construct;                                                             
    while(true) {                                                                 
        string current;                                                           
        getline(cin, current);                                                    
        assert(!cin.eof());                                                       
        if (current.find("end") == 0) { break; }                              
        cout << current << endl;                                        
        construct.append(current);                                          
    }                                                                             
    cout << construct << endl;                                          
    return 0;                                                                     
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -Wall -std=c++0x
```

Input: `input.txt`

```
abcdef
ghij
end
```

Output: `./main < input.txt`

```
abcdef
ghij
ghijef
```

If I type the input instead of using a file, it works as expected. Also I get the same result with gcc (linux) and clang (mac os).

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/5FOLme). Could we see some sample input and output?

Comment: Works fine in Visual Studio 2010 Express too..

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In Cygwin it shows only the last line, but in Netbeans it shows the entire content. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My input file was an ascii file with CRLF line terminators (and I'm using a mac). The `construct` variable was created correctly, but it wasn't displayed properly by the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of my .txt file over to Word and deleted all of the hard returns, which worked, but that is not always ideal or possible. The character encoding did not seem to have an impact. What solved it is when I appended a line break as well as the string.

```
Text::Text(string file) {
    ifstream in;
    string line;
    in.open( file.c_str() ); // because the file name is a parameter decided at runtime in my code
    while(getline(in,line,'\n')){
        fileContents.append(line+"\n"); // fixed by adding "\n" here
    }
    cout << "\n Final product:\n";
    cout << fileContents;
}
```